# I created a dropdown list and how to display the other columns data of selected item?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this is my code for dropdown list

```
 <?php 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM parts";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 echo "<select name='name' class='ed'>";
 echo "<option id='0'> --Select Part Name-- </option>";
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 $op1=$row['part_description'];
 $op2=$op1.$row['price'];
 $op3=$op2.$row['weight'];
 echo "<option value='" . $row['part_description'] ."'>" .$op3 ."</option>";
 echo $op3;

 }
 echo "</select>";
 ?>
```

I have 3 columns for my database
part_description, price and weight. In the dropdownlist i created, you can select stored items at part_description. What I want to do is if I select that item in drop down list it will also display also the price and weight. But the display should be out of the box.

Please help me thanks

Comment: `SELECT part_description, price, weight FROM parts` then access the respective indices

Comment: How can I display price and weight values as selecting items in part_description?

Comment: my suggestion to you is create a ready array, then just use the id, then you can access that particular row, or if its too many (like 1000 rows), just use the ID and create another select statement

Comment: Hello im just very new in web development can you show me some reference of your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT part_description FROM parts";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='name' class='ed'>";
echo "<option id='0'> --Select Part Name--</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 $op1=$row['part_description'];
 $op2=$op1.$row['price'];
 $op3=$op2.$row['weight'];
echo "<option value='" . $row['part_description'] ."'>" .$op3 ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

This is for print three value in single option tag.
And let me know Is this your expectation.

Comment: I got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$op2' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\AstroCigarette\admin\addquote.php on line 128                          Im trying to do is if I select an item from drop down it will display the weight and price with that selected row. Please help Im just newbie

Comment: theres no error but the output is still the same, I need is I select any items from dropdown list then it will also load the price and weight of that selected item.

Comment: but the display should be outside the box

Comment: increase the size of your option box.  input,textarea,option{
 width:250px;
 
} try with pixel whatever you want

Comment: Hi my option box width is already big enough but all 3 column information is inside that option box how can I make the other 2 data transfer outside or in other box? please help thanks

Comment: share the screen shot.That is help to find solution to your problem.

Comment: How can I make 2 values print outside the option tag if I select the item from the menu list? I want to print price and weight outside the option

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Javascript.

```
<?php    
$parts = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT part_description, price, weight FROM parts");
$theParts = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($parts)) {
    $part = [];
    $part['description'] = $row['part_description'];
    $part['price'] = $row['price'];
    $part['weight'] = $row['weight'];
    $theParts[] = $part;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theParts = <?php echo(json_encode($theParts));?>;
    function createDropDown() {
        var theDropdown = "<select name='name' id='theDropDown' class='ed' onchange='didChange()'>";
        theDropdown += "<option value='0'>--Select Part Name--</option>";
        theParts.forEach(function(entry) {
            theDropdown += "<option value='" + entry['description'] + "'>" + entry['description'] + "</option>";
        });
        theDropdown += "</select>";
        return theDropdown;
    }
    function didChange() {
         var e = document.getElementById("theDropDown");
         var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
         var price = null;
         var weight = null;
         theParts.forEach(function(entry) {
               if (entry['description']==str) {
                     price = entry['price'];
                     weight = entry['weight'];
               }
         });
    }
</script>
```

(I typed this code directly into StackOverflow and haven't tested it but it should work)

EDIT:
Here's how to do it using MySQL, although I [don't recommend](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) using it.

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database', $conn);
$results = mysql_query("SELECT part_description, price, weight FROM parts");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    //Same as above.
}
```

Comment: hello im just very new in web development when i try your code i got an error like this

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\AstroCigarette\admin\addquote.php on line 121

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\AstroCigarette\admin\addquote.php on line 121

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\AstroCigarette\admin\addquote.php on line 123

Comment: Looks like you are using [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), you should be using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). It says parameter 1 is null, so you should create the connection first. `$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");`

Comment: how can I convert this for mysql only?